# Xamarin Forms: Not able to create a corner radius for a two column layout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a grid layout with a height of 8px with cornered radius horizontally as below snapshot.

[image: Design] : https://ibb.co/s1dkpnw

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,24" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*">
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="8">
                    </RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Frame CornerRadius="8" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="8">
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Lime"></Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Label>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
```

I'm able to get the UI as in the below snapshot.

[image: Actual result] : https://ibb.co/7nLTgdL

I'm not able to get the UI displyed within the frame visible, although i'm getting a cornered radius for a two columned layout. It just shows a empty frame.

Please let me know how to design the XAML UI to get the UI as in the design snapshot.

Comment: Frame override the other colors on android. If you use Xamarin forms 3.4 please replace Frame with BoxView (now supported and corner radius for this) or you can try RoundedBoxView from nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Got the UI aligned by pushing the Grid within the frame control as below,

```
<Frame CornerRadius="8" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="8">
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*">
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*">
                </ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="8">
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Lime"></Label>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Label>

        </Grid>
</Frame>
```

Answer (score 0):

AbsoluteLayout can help you:

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
         <Frame
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,150,8"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
            BackgroundColor="#0086C9"
            CornerRadius="7" />

        <Frame
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="120,0,150,8"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
            BackgroundColor="#D8D8D8"
            CornerRadius="7" />

        <Frame
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="120,0,30,8"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="None"
            BackgroundColor="#0086C9"
            CornerRadius="1" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Output: https://i.ibb.co/jh6QmBL/ss.png